# How to keep a for loop running when you save a file as a different name and then re-open the original file for the next iteration?

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a macro to split a file that has multiple names and data associated to that name on multiple tabs. The goal is to have individual files for each name in the file so I can send that person their personal performance stats (IC is the persons job role).

In the code shown below I'm creating a filter and deleting everything that isn't the selected name. This is repeated for each data tab. No errors are appearing when i run the code, however, since i save the file as a different name and then re-open the original file, the loop is stopped and doesn't continue onto the next name. Is there a way get the code to run off the original file again once it's reopen so the loop can continue onto the next name?

Extract of code;

```
Sub Individual_IC_Filter()

Dim List_IC_Names As Range
Set List_IC_Names = Range("List_IC_Names")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C10").Value = Range("C10").Value

For Each cell In List_IC_Names

    'Filter Dashboard
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Cells(2, 7).Value = cell.Value

        
    'Selects IC Name in IC-Level Table tab and deletes other ICs (This section of code is repeated for each tab in the spreadsheet)
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IC-Level Table").Range("IC_Data")
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & cell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IC-Level Table").Range("IC_Data")
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IC-Level Table").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IC-Level Table").Range("IC_Data")
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=cell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With

        'Save as new file
    FName = cell.value & " Dashboard - LATAM - " & Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("AI3"), "YYYY MM DD") & ".xlsm"
    FName2 = "IC Dashboard - LATAM - " & Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("AI3"), "YYYY MM DD") & ".xlsm"
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
            "Y:\Financials\2022\IC Goals\Master Region Score Card Files\2022 09 26\Regional Cuts\LATAM\" & FName
    
    'Open original IC file

    Workbooks.Open "Y:\Financials\2022\IC Goals\Master Region Score Card Files\2022 09 26\" & FName2
    
    
    'Saves & close split IC workbook
    Workbooks(FName).Close savechanges:=Flase    
    
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Create a new workbook and copy the worksheet into the new workbook. Then filter, save, and close it. That way you will always be operating in `ThisWorkbook` to keep your macro going.

Comment: Thanks Peter, there is an interactive dashboard and multiple tab tabs that have formulas referencing data from other tabs. Copying across the data normally links the formulas and dashboard to the original workbook.

Comment: Is there a way to duplicate a file while keeping the original file open? So save as but now have 2 files open with the same data?

Comment: See if your version of Excel has the [SaveCopyAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.SaveCopyAs) feature available. Then you'll open that saved copy, such as `Dim copyWB As Workbook; Set copyWB = Workbooks.Open Filename:="<thecopyfilename>"`